# Create a site template without using "save site as template"

Tags: sharepoint-designer, page-layout

I need to create a template for publishing page without using save site as template option. I need to design header and left navigation within that template itself and reuse that in other pages. How can I implement this.. Provide any suggestions.. Is it possible to implement..??

Actually I have to Create Design Template instead of a master page layout to apply to all pages except admin pages and my design is will look like

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you have described in your question is not called a `site template` , it's called a `page layout` as shown below :

[image]

So **To create a page layout follow the mentioned steps below**

- Browse to your publishing site.
- In the upper-right corner of the page, choose the gear icon, and then choose Design Manager.
- In Design Manager, in the left navigation pane, choose Edit Page Layouts.
- Choose Create a page layout.
- In the Create a Page Layout dialog box, enter a name for your page layout.

Continue the details Steps at [Creating a Custom Page Layout in SharePoint 2013](http://blog.navantis.com/create-a-custom-page-layout-in-sharepoint-2013/)

**Note** : you can't save site as a template in Publishing site.

Comment: I want to create a header without using master page is there any way to do this..?

Comment: Ya we can't save site as template then how can create a site template for publishing site

Comment: Dear @JeevaJeyapaul , Regarding the first comment you can do this by creating application page but in this case, you will not be able to use it as a page layout for other pages as you need  ! so I suggest to create a custom master page with the header and footer that you need and use it only for your custom page layout , to change page master page for a page layout check http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/25011/how-to-change-the-master-page-associated-to-a-custom-page-layout

Comment: Regarding the Second comment ,  unfortunately, you can't create a site template from publishing site, meanwhile, there's more workaround to do this but it's not worked properly !

So my advise to you to create a team site and customize your template then save it as a template and if you need the publishing feature try to enable it in site features

Please don't hesitate to tell me if you need any clarification

Comment: Actually I have to Create Design Template instead of a master page layout to apply to all pages except admin pages and my design is will look like